# using an observer of livedata to call a function

Tags: android, kotlin

Trying to find out how to cause a function to run when the value of a livedata object in my viewmodel changes. All the examples I can find in the google dev docs show how to use an explicitly declared observer to set a text view in the fragment, which is very not helpful because it's way easier to just use databinding.** I need to call a function that has nothing whatever to do with the UI as soon as the livedata gets updated. I would prefer this be all handled in the ViewModel itself, but I don't mind very much if the observer is in the fragment and calls the function in the ViewModel.

So say I have the following in my sharedViewModel

```
private val _okhttpOutputText = MutableLiveData<String?>("")
val okhttpOutputText: LiveData<String?> = _okhttpOutputText
```

and in my fragment, at the end of onViewCreated(), I have

```
sharedViewModel.okhttpOutputText.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, { newString ->
           myFunction(newString)
       })
```

This not only doesn't work, it crashes when the fragment loads

Any help appreciated

**EDIT**

Nevermind! Got it working. I did two things wrong. The crash was caused by there being a blank initial value in MutableLiveData. Not sure why that was a problem, but it was. Secondly, I was right about my syntax being off. The google developer training codelabs didn't bother to give an example of using observers for anything but updating UI. It should have been:

```
sharedViewModel.okhttpOutputText.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer{ 
           myFunction(it)
       })
```

That worked. And then after AS recommended I remove the redundant SAM and then move the lambda out of the parenthesis it became

```
sharedViewModel.okhttpOutputText.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
           myFunction(it)
       }
```

And that also worked

Comment: "it crashes when the fragment loads" - in order for SO users to help please include the relevant stack trace.

Comment: I will when I get home again. I thought there must be something wrong with my syntax because if I replace newString ->
           myFunction(newString)
       })  with newString -> binding.textview.text = newString ?: "" it works perfectly. Sadly, updating a textview isn't what I need